# How to maintain different country versions of same language in Django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I would like to have a few different versions of the same language in Django, customized for different countries (e.g. `locale/en`, `locale/en_CA`, `locale/en_US`, etc.). If there is no language for specific country I would expect to use the default language version (`locale/en`)).

Then in the settings file for each site I specify `LANGUAGE_CODE` and `LANGUAGES`.

For some reason, even if I specify the following settings, the `locale/en_US` translations are still used:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

Though I clearly specify that the language code should be `en` (not `en-us`).

Am I missing something? Already tried to find the answer in multiple places, including Django documentation.

Comment: Actually, if Django supports it, you'd want to maintain minimal entries in en_CA, en_US etc and fallback case-by-case on main *en* most of the time, because most words are the same across all flavors. I.e. pick from the specific if you find a word in it *neighbour* vs *neighbor* but leave *house* in main only.

Comment: That's correct, but the problem is Django for some reason uses "en_US", even if I simply specify "en". Any clues? Edit: if I specify "en-ca", it properly uses "en_CA".

Comment: No, unfortunately this bit of advice came from my experience on another system and was just a pointer to keep your translation costs down.  Haven't used Django translation support yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround to the issue would be to add following snippet to your `settings.py` file.

```
import locale
locale.locale_alias.pop('en', None)
```

Special credit to Venelin Stoykov who was able to investigate the behavior of the Python `locale` module.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quirk of Python (not specifically Django) and the gettext module.

Ticket [8626](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8626) was raised on the Django issue tracker around the time of the 1.0 release and after some suggestions and debate, the Django devs deemed it a "won't fix".

There are suggestions in the ticket thread to use 'en-en' as the default. My memory is a little rough but if I recall correctly this approach didn't play well with other parts of my i18n tooling (e.g. the pox library). I gave up and settled for using en-US as the default for the project and listing the other variants (e.g. en-au) as alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for giving a direction - bounty given to you! The thing is I am using i18n_patterns as well for having language customized URLs. The trick with "en-us" or "en-en" might work, but will change the URL structure of the application. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Could you settle for having the en-US translations at both your general English (.../en/) and the US (.../en-us/) URLs? To be honest my preference is to keep language/locales out of the URLs but perhaps you can share your URL scheme in another question and I can give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest you to put a breakpoint into the  LocaleMiddleware Class?

In this way, you might found out a clue which thing was actually getting your way from getting the right Language.

Becaue according the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/middleware/locale/#LocaleMiddleware) of LocaleMiddleware Class and the [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)
, there could be so many things can affect the result.

Comment: Right, I am aware about that, but it is not the case, since I am using `i18n_patterns` and that's the first thing `LocaleMiddleware` is trying to look for.

Comment: Ok, I just tried adding breakpoints in the `process_request` and `process_response` methods of the `LocaleMiddleware`, and language the is correctly set to `en`. Even though, the `en_US` locale is used.